# How to transform Javascript object with groupby and reduce properly?

Tags: javascript, list, sorting

I need to transform following object

```
  [
        {
            "name" : "sazzad",
            "type" : "credit",
            "amount" : 10
        },{
            "name" : "sazzad",
            "type" : "credit",
            "amount" : 21
        },{
            "name" : "sazzad",
            "type" : "debit",
            "amount" : 10
        },{
            "name" : "lopa",
            "type" : "credit",
            "amount" : 20
        },{
            "name" : "lopa",
            "type" : "debit",
            "amount" : 10
        }
]
```

Into following

```
[
  {
    "name": "sazzad",
    "balance": 21
  },
  {
    "name": "lopa",
    "balance": 10
  }
]
```

I have used following code to transform it already

```
    function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
        const map = new Map();
        list.forEach((item) => {
            const key = keyGetter(item);
            const collection = map.get(key);
            if (!collection) {
                map.set(key, [item]);
            } else {
                collection.push(item);
            }
        });
        return map;
    }
    const grouped = groupBy(accountTransactions, transaction => transaction.name);
    const balanceSheet = []
    for (const [key, value] of grouped) {
        balanceSheet.push(
            {
                "name": grouped.get(key)[0].name,
                "balance" : grouped.get(key).map(at => {
                    if (at.type === "credit") {
                        return at.amount
                    }else {
                        return -at.amount
                    }
                }).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
            }
        );
    }
```

But I think for a large data set it will not perform very well.
So is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why is the desired result not a hash map? E.g. if you want to know the balance of `const balanceName = "sazzad";` you have to do a linear search like `balanceSheet.find(({name}) => name === balanceName).balance` instead of a constant property access like `balanceSheet[balanceName].balance`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an object with keys equal to the `name` values, updating the `balance` value based on the `type` and `amount` from each object in the transactions array. Then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to convert that to an array:

```js
const transactions = [
  { "name": "sazzad", "type": "credit", "amount": 10 },
  { "name": "sazzad", "type": "credit", "amount": 21 },
  { "name": "sazzad", "type": "debit", "amount": 10 },
  { "name": "lopa", "type": "credit", "amount": 20 },
  { "name": "lopa", "type": "debit", "amount": 10 }
];

const balances = Object.values(transactions.reduce((c, {name, type, amount}) => {
  c[name] = c[name] || { name, 'balance' : 0 };
  c[name].balance += type == 'credit' ? amount : -amount;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(balances);
```

Note that you may find an object more useful:

```js
const transactions = [
  { "name": "sazzad", "type": "credit", "amount": 10 },
  { "name": "sazzad", "type": "credit", "amount": 21 },
  { "name": "sazzad", "type": "debit", "amount": 10 },
  { "name": "lopa", "type": "credit", "amount": 20 },
  { "name": "lopa", "type": "debit", "amount": 10 }
];

const balances = transactions.reduce((c, {name, type, amount}) => {
  c[name] = c[name] || { 'balance' : 0 };
  c[name].balance += type == 'credit' ? amount : -amount;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(balances);
```

Comment: This is an improvement because it avoids creating another `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

if it  helps... ?

```js
const transactions = 
  [ { name: 'sazzad', type: 'credit', amount: 10 } 
  , { name: 'sazzad', type: 'credit', amount: 21 } 
  , { name: 'sazzad', type: 'debit',  amount: 10 } 
  , { name: 'lopa',   type: 'credit', amount: 20 } 
  , { name: 'lopa',   type: 'debit',  amount: 10 } 
  ] 

const DebCred = {credit : +1, debit: -1 }

const balances = Object.entries(transactions.reduce((c, {name, type, amount}) =>
  {
  c[name] = c[name] || 0
  c[name] += ( DebCred[type] * amount )
  return c
  },{})).map(([k,v])=>({name:k,balance:v}))

console.log(balances);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```